# move from View (URL) to another with onclick action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

how i can move from list view to edit view when I select (on click) the required record from list?

I can do what i want when I click on a specific button as it is cleared  in the following code but i want to remove this button and  Replaced it with a on click action.

who can help me please?

```
{ title: '@Resources.General.View', template: '<a href="ViewIndividuals?individualsNo=#=IN_InNo#" class="btn btn-default btn-bordered" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>' },
```

this is my code :

 `var grid = $("#MyGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds,
            // inject common kendo settings
            @Html.Partial("_kendo_JS_Setting")
            columns:
            [
                { field: "IN_InNo", width: 100, title: '@WebHelper.LocalResources(this, "IndividualsNumber")' },
                { field: "IN_Name", width: 100, title: '@Resources.General.Name' },
                { field: "IN_Address1", width: 100, title: '@WebHelper.LocalResources(this, "IN_Address1")' },
                { field: "IN_Mobile1", width: 100, title: '@WebHelper.LocalResources(this, "IN_Mobile1")' },
                { field: "IN_CreationDate", width: 100, title: '@Resources.General.CreationDate', template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(IN_CreationDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #", groupable: false },
                { field: "IN_CreatedBy.FullName", width: 100, title: '@Resources.General.CreatedBy' },
                @{ field: "ModificationDate", width: 100, title: '@Resources.General.LastUpdate' },
                { field: "ModifiedBy.FullName", width: 100, title: '@Resources.General.ModifiedBy' },@
                { title: '@Resources.General.View', template: '' },
                @{ title: '@Resources.General.Edit', template: '' },
                { title: '@Resources.General.Delete', template: '' },
                { title: '@WebHelper.LocalResources(this, "Attachments")', template: '' },@
            ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");
        // add tooltip`

Comment: this is my code:
 { title: '@Resources.General.View', template: '<a href="ViewIndividuals?individualsNo=#=IN_InNo#" class="btn btn-default btn-bordered" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>' },

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of adding relevant information in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, a relevant code is missing and I can only guess what you would like to achieve, what I'd do is to use the HTML data attribute set on the row where you will pass the link for the Edit view, and then add a click event handler for the click on that row.

```
<tr class="item-row" data-href="@Url.Action("ViewIndividuals","ControllerName", new { individualsNo= individualsNo})">
   <td>x</td>
   <td>xx</td>
</tr>
```

Next step is to create the jQuery event handler:

```
$('.item-row').click(function(){
   var url = $(this).data('href');
   window.location = url;
});
```

Of course, the action can be binded to any element, not only to the table row. Just pay attention where you are adding the data-href attribute.

Also, data attribute can be named according to your wishes e.g. data-link, data-url, data-action,...

Comment: it's ok but my record is not inserted in table because I am use kendo tool like this code :

Comment: @Moro It doesn't matter if it's a table, a div, or any other element. The idea behind it is to pass the data (in this case URL of the action) and get it on click using jQuery.